# How do I update the messageRead attribute in my MongoDb object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following object stored in MongoDb. I am sending a `messageRead` attribute inside my `messages` array.

[image]

I have tried:

```
 collection.updateOne({ '_id': ObjectId(employeeID) }, 

                      { 
                        
                        "$set": { 
                  
                          "userObject.messages.message.message_uuid" : {  employeeMessageUpdateUUID, "messageRead" : employeeMessageRead } 
                      
                      
                      
                      }
```

but it does not work. I find the object i'm looking for through the `_id`, and then try to find the `message` using the `message_uuid` however the `messageRead` attribute is not updating. I am clearly using the wrong Mongo query.. What should my `$set` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) operator to do that:

```
collection.updateOne(
  { 
    '_id': ObjectId(employeeID),
    'userObject.messages.message.message_uuid': employeeMessageUpdateUUID
  }, 
  {
    $set: { 'userObject.messages.$.message.messageRead': employeeMessageRead }
  }
)...
```